# синтаксис словосочетания

Tags: синтаксис

К словосочетанию **встать поздно** как правильно задать вопрос?

**Когда?** или **Как?**

Comment: Смажьте клавишу Пробел!

Answer (score 1):

Встать когда? - поздно. Обстоятельство времени.

Comment: И здесь коррозия препинания. Ах, да! Тема: синтаксис.